# Traceroute public ip decrease latency

Tags: amazon-ec2, request, latency

I have a system that makes requests and posts for a page in Italy, and I need to reduce my latency to the maximum, because it interferes directly in the performance of what I need to register. The service in Italy is not mine, I'm just automating a routine, using Python for this. I have tested several cloud processing services (aws ec2, google cloud, italian clouds), and my latency does not fall below 20ms. When I run the traceroute, in all services, I see that my requests are leaving Europe and going to the US (ips 107.162.X.X), and then return to Europe. Is there any way they will not leave Europe?

> ------Germany start: 1    static.129.213.201.195.clients.your-server.de [195.201.213.129]     0ms     4ms     1ms      2  core11.nbg1.hetzner.com
>   [213.239.229.153]     0ms     3ms     0.75ms   3  juniper4.dc2.nbg1.hetzner.com
>   [213.239.203.138]     0ms     0ms     0ms      4  nug-b1-link.telia.net
>   [213.248.70.0]    0ms     0ms     0ms      5  ffm-bb3-link.telia.net
>   [62.115.113.146]  3ms     4ms     3.25ms   6  ffm-b1-link.telia.net
>   [62.115.121.1]    4ms     7ms     5ms      7
>     f5networks-ic-341210-ffm-b1.c.telia.net [62.115.169.109]    3ms     3ms
>     3ms      8  107.162.79.3    3ms     5ms     3.5ms    9  107.162.67.110  26ms
>     107ms   52.75ms      10     85.116.228.2    25ms    25ms    25ms
>
> -- Milan IT start
>
> 1. IT 192.165.67.0     Loss%  Snt   Last  Avg   Best  Wrst  StDev AS Name                         PTR
> 2. IT 192.165.67.1     0.0%   20    1.1   1.5   0.7   10.1  2.0   34971
> 3. IT 217.171.38.133   0.0%   20    0.2   1.0   0.2   9.6   2.2   20836
> 4. EU 213.248.84.128   5.0%   20    0.6   1.5   0.4   10.9  2.9   1299
> 5. EU 62.115.142.140   0.0%   20    9.4   9.7   9.3   14.8  1.2   1299
> 6. EU 62.115.116.160   0.0%   20    9.2   12.5  9.2   56.1  10.6  1299
> 7. EU 62.115.169.109   0.0%   20    9.4   10.2  9.4   17.0  2.0   1299
> 8. US 107.162.79.3     0.0%   20    9.4   10.5  9.4   18.5  2.4   55002
> 9. US 107.162.67.114   0.0%   20    41.2  35.8  29.7  69.4  11.6  55002
> 10. IT 85.116.228.2     0.0%   20    28.6  28.9  28.5  34.4  1.3   34699
>
> -- Paris FR start
>
> 1. FR 51.15.179.0      Loss%  Snt   Last  Avg   Best  Wrst  StDev AS Name                         PTR 1   FR 51.15.179.1      0.0%   20
>      0.5   0.5   0.4   0.9   0.0   12876  2   FR 51.158.8.56      0.0%   20    0.5   0.5   0.3   1.2   0.0   12876  3   FR 195.154.2.168    0.0%   20    1.2   1.3   1.1   1.5   0.0   12876  4   NL 212.3.235.201    0.0%   20    1.9   2.0   1.9   2.3   0.0   3356   5      ???              100.0  20    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   - 6   EU 80.231.153.65    0.0%   20    2.2   2.3   2.1   3.9   0.3   6453   7   EU 195.219.87.9     0.0%   20    29.1  30.0  29.0  42.6  2.9   6453   8   EU 195.219.87.88    0.0%   20    20.1  20.5  20.0  25.4  1.2   6453   9   CH 195.219.61.48    0.0%   20    12.3  11.7  11.5  12.5  0.0   6453   10  EU 195.219.148.186  0.0%   20    17.0  17.1  16.9  18.5  0.0   6453   11  US 107.162.79.3     0.0%   20    11.6  12.2  11.6  14.4  0.8   55002  12  US 107.162.67.110   0.0%   20    41.3  36.8  32.0  64.7  7.7   55002  13  IT 85.116.228.2     0.0%   20    31.3  31.3  31.2  31.7  0.0   34699

I wish I could reduce latency as much as possible. Could you suggest something?

Comment: Note that it is physically impossible for traffic to cross the Atlantic Ocean with a round trip time of less than approximately 75 milliseconds, so your test tool is definitely misidentifying the location of these addresses.  It is not uncommon for IP addresses to show a location related to the company to which the addresses have been allocated, unrelated to the location of the device assigned the address.

Comment: I dont want to cross ocean. I wanna my requests stay at europe.

Comment: I understand.  What I am saying is that your traffic **is not** going to the US, even though the traceroute gives this impression.  It can't be, because if it were, the round trip times would be much higher than they already are.

Comment: Can i have a way to reduce the latency? Independent where i do the requests (germany, italy or france) the latency is the same.

Comment: The fact that no matter where you are, the latency is the same, implies that there is unlikely to be anything you can do.  But also... ~30ms is not really noteworthy as latencies go, for most purposes.  Are you sure this is the cause of your problems?

Comment: I need to send some posts and parse the html response. The parse and selection of the tags is taking around 0.1 ms, I do not perform any operations that do IO with the disk. I think my main bottleneck for optimization is latency.